# How do I create a search for the items in an section in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I need to create a search logic for NameString instead of NameSection. I was able to make the search bar here ([How do I create a search bar for SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66897732/how-do-i-create-a-search-bar-for-swiftui)). I want to search names instead of sections. I tried numerous times but it won't work. NameString thinks it's not String.

So in the JSON File there are sections like Monday, Wednesday, etc, currently the code supports a search for those instead of items in those days like Name11, Name 12. I need to create a search for those items.

Here is what I have

```
import SwiftUI
var counter = 0

struct ContentView: View {
    let name = Bundle.main.decode([NameSection].self, from: "name copy.json")
    let names = Bundle.main.decode([NameString].self,from: "name copy.json")
    
    @State private var searchText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack {
                SearchBarView(searchText: $searchText)
                List{
                    ForEach(name.filter{$0.name.hasPrefix(searchText) || searchText == ""}, id:\.self) {
                        section in
                            Section(header: Text(section.name)) {
                                ForEach(section.items){ item in
                                    NavigationLink(destination:
                                                TrackerDetails(item: item)){
                                                    Tracker(item: item)
                                                 }
                                        
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    }
                    .navigationTitle("Names")
                    .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
                }
            }
        }
    
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct NameSection: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    var items: [NameItem]
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}

struct NameItem: Codable, Equatable, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String

    var mainImage: String {
        name.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "-").lowercased()
    }

    var thumbnailImage: String {
        "\(mainImage)-thumb"
    }

    #if DEBUG
    static let example = NameItem(id: UUID(), name: "Maple French Toast")
    #endif
}

struct NameString: Codable, Identifiable{
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    
}
```

```
JSON

[{
        "id": "EF1CC5BB-4785-4D8E-AB98-5FA4E00B6A66",
        "name": "Monday",
        "items": [{
                "id": "EF1CC5BB-4785-4D8E-AB98-5FA4E00B6A67",
                "name": "Name11"
            },
            {
                "id": "EF1CC5BB-4785-4D8E-AB98-5FA4E00B6A68",
                "name": "Name12"
            },
            {
                "id": "EF1CC5BB-4785-4D8E-AB98-5FA4E00B6A69",
                "name": "Name13"
            }

        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "EF1CC5BB-4785-4D8E-AB98-5FA4E00B6A67",
        "name": "Wednesday",
        "items": [{
                "id": "EF1CC5BB-4785-4D8E-AB98-5FA4E00B6A60",
                "name": "Name21"
            },
            {
                "id": "EF1CC5BB-4785-4D8E-AB98-5FA4E00B6A61",
                "name": "Name22"
            },
            {
                "id": "EF1CC5BB-4785-4D8E-AB98-5FA4E00B6A62",
                "name": "Name23"
            }

        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "EF1CC5BB-4785-4D8E-AB98-5FA4E00B6A90",
        "name": "SATURDAY",
        "items": [{
                "id": "EF1CC5BB-4785-4D8E-AB98-5FA4E00B6A96",
                "name": "Name21"
            },
            {
                "id": "EF1CC5BB-4785-4D8E-AB98-5FA4E00B6A94",
                "name": "Name22"
            },
            {
                "id": "EF1CC5BB-4785-4D8E-AB98-5FA4E00B6A35",
                "name": "Name23"
            }

        ]
    },




]
```

JSON Decoder

```
import UIKit

extension Bundle {
    func decode<T: Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, from file: String) -> T {
        guard let url = self.url(forResource: file, withExtension: nil) else {
            fatalError("Failed to locate \(file) in bundle.")
        }

        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
            fatalError("Failed to load \(file) from bundle.")
        }

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()

        guard let loaded = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) else {
            fatalError("Failed to decode \(file) from bundle.")
        }

        return loaded
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating NameString? It seems redundant as the information is contained within NameSection? What is is that you are actually trying to achieve because your question is not clear as you have `name` listed in many parts of the data, which one are your trying to search on? How should the list look when you have performed a successful search?

Comment: So in the JSON File there are sections like Monday, Wednesday, etc, currently the code supports a search for those instead of items in those days like Name11, Name 12. I need to create a search for those items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At your request in a comment on yesterdays question, here's a brief function to filter the results based on the name of the item:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let name = Bundle.main.decode([NameSection].self, from: "name.json")
    
    @State private var searchText = ""
    
    var filteredItems : [NameSection] {
        if searchText.isEmpty { return name }
        return name.map { nameSection in
            var nameSectionCopy = nameSection
            nameSectionCopy.items = nameSection.items.filter { $0.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) }
            return nameSectionCopy
        }.filter { !$0.items.isEmpty }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack {
                SearchBarView(searchText: $searchText)
                List{
                    ForEach(filteredItems, id:\.self) {
                        section in
                            Section(header: Text(section.name)) {
                                ForEach(section.items){ item in
                                    Text(item.name)
                                }
                            }
                    }
                    .navigationTitle("Names")
                    .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It checks for a case-insensitive match (see that both `searchText` and `name` are `lowercased()`) that appears anywhere in the name field (see `contains()`).

It filters out sections (ie `Day`s) that don't have any items (see the last `filter` of `filteredItems`).

I didn't have access to your `TrackerDetails` or `Tracker`, so you'll have to re-implement your `NavigationLink`.